# Подскажите как обратиться к элементу в localsorage правильно? Не получается сохранить активный класс js

Tags: javascript, localstorage, this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myDIV li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myDIV li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", "true");
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");
    if (blockIsActive == "true") {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

И не получится, потому что в `$(document).ready` в `this` будет вовсе не активный элемент. Не надо бездумно код копипастить.

Сохраняй какой-то другой признак, например id, текст или номер.